# Asp.net Core: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, fetch-api

I am using react as a front-end and asp.net core as a back-end. I am using fetch API for API request but I am getting Cors error on the browser console saying: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44316/api/auth/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

My ConfigureServices method is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("myPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(name: "Default")));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IJwtHelper, JwtHelper>();
        }
```

And the Configure method is:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("myPolicy");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
            });
        }
```

In react I created a form submit event and its looks like:

```
const submitRegisterForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch(
      "https://localhost:44316/api/auth/register",{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          password,
          role,
        })
      });

    setRedirectTo(true);
  };
```

This the output I am getting in Brower network tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows
In your ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ClientPermission", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

and in your Configure method

```
app.UseCors("ClientPermission");
```

Comment: Not working. The aproach is same as mine. I am directly setting the policy in pipeline

Comment: You added the AddCors method before the services.AddControllers() right? and UseCors() before UseRouting and UseEndpoints?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question and added complete both methods

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the console error as well to the question?

Comment: Made a change in policy. Try this as well. Since you are using signalr as well, this will be needed i think

Comment: For some reason I was missing this line, when I added it to my program.cs it removed the cors errors. Thanks

            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)

Answer (score 0):

On the client side for localhost request use http and not https

```js
const submitRegisterForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:44316/api/auth/register",{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          password,
          role,
        })
      });
       setRedirectTo(true);
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: My server is running on https

Answer (score 0):

The placement order codes in asp.net core v6 should be as follows in program.cs

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Also in front and in jsx you should send the headers as follow:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": 'application/json',
"authorization": "Bearer " + token,
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
```